# Why is a double "==" and "equals" to a Double?

Tags: java, equality

Please explain the following situation:

```
double d3=(double) 1;
Double d4=new Double(1);
System.out.println(d4==d3); // true
System.out.println(d4.equals(d3)) // true
```

Why do both of these print `true`?

Comment: what is weird in this?

Comment: You need to ask more specific question, than "why is it so?"

Comment: You need to read about [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: @VD' It is weird in Java because it's special-cased magic ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification 15.21.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
>
> Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).

*Unboxing conversion* is exactly what's happening here: `d4` is unboxed to its value, `1.0`, which is then compared to `d3`'s value, which is also `1.0`.

From your question, it seems like you're expecting `d3 == d4` to be `false` because they are different "references"; however, primitive types can never be a reference, so any comparison for equality to a primitive type requires a conversion to that primitive type. We can see this from [the JLS rules regarding object equality in 15.21.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3):

> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.

This is the only situation where object equality occurs, and it does not include primitive types.

Comment: thanks. it helpful with me.in addion. please expain me mechanism of two expression. Double d3=(double) 1;
  double d4=new Double(1);

Comment: @LêQuốcÂn I'm not sure what you mean - feel free to create a new question and link to it from here.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a primitive type, while `Double` is a class which acts as a *wrapper* around a `double`.  (This is why, for instance, you'd get an error if you tried to use `d3.equal`)  As a convenience, comparisons between the two work as you'd expect just by considering their numeric values; in this case, since they both are 1, they are considered equal.